# How can we unit test the sessionstorage in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to unit testing in Angular, and I am trying to test the sessionstorage and localstorage.

My code is:

```
subscribe(data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('myProductDetail', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

subscribe(data) {
        LocalStorage.setItem('dummyname', data[0].name);
    }
```

Is it a good practice to do unit testing for session, local storage and private classes?

I am trying to follow the example code below to mock my localstorage and sessionstorage.

```
beforeEach(function () {
  var store = {};

  spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake(function (key) {
    return store[key];
  });
  spyOn(sessionStorage, 'setItem').andCallFake(function (key, value) {
    return store[key] = value + '';
  });
  spyOn(localStorage, 'clear').andCallFake(function () {
      store = {};
  });
});
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you test a built-in API?

Comment: I'm sure he is not trying to test the built-in API, possibly he's trying to put values on sessionStorage to see how his application behaves

Answer (score 6):

See thread https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/299 for more detail about differences in browsers.

Method 0:

Leave as is. Firefox or phantomjs will setup storage and you can check value in storage after.
If You still need custom reaction You can spy on it in `beforeEach` section.

Method 1: just spy on `sessionStorage`.
Works with phantomjs and may be chrome but does not in FF.

```js
const store = {};
spyOn(sessionStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake((key) => {
  return store[key];
});
spyOn(sessionStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake((key, value) => {
  console.log(key);
  return store[key] = value + '';
});
```

Method 2: replace `sessionStorage`.
Will work in firefox but not in phantomjs because it prohibits `sessionStorage` replacement. 
But phantomjs allows to spy on it so method 1 will work.

```js
const mock = (() => {
  let store = {};
  return {
    getItem: (key) => {
      return store[key];
    },
    setItem: (key, value) => {
      console.log(key);
      store[key] = value + '';
    },
    clear: () => {
      store = {};
    }
  };
})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: mock, writable: true });
```

Method 3: spy on `Storage.prototype`.
Will work on all implementation but replaces all storages.

```js
spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem').and.callFake((key, value) => {
  console.log(key);
  // some logic like in prev examples
});
// other spyOn
```

You can combine method 1 and 2 like author of this post did for prev version https://blog.bradleygore.com/2014/09/17/angular-unit-testing-pt-1-local-storage/.